# How to if-call VAT No in Odoo TAX report

Tags: odoo-15

In Odoo 15 TAX report
Company name is exist there but VAT number is not.
I looked at the code I found that Comapny name is called by
`<strong>Company:</strong><p t-esc="res_company.name"/>`
I wanted to call TAX ID and Company_registry if the field is filled

So I tried

```
<t t-if="res_company.vat">
<strong>VAT No:</strong>
<t t-esc="res_company.vat"/>
</t>
<t t-if="res_company.company_registry">
<br/>
<strong>CR:</strong>
<t t-esc="res_company.company_registry"/>
</t>
```

Now it is working fine.
Thank you

Comment: in the 5th line why don't you use `<t t-if="res_company.company_registry">` in place of `<t t-if="res_company.vat">` so if the CR exist it will show otherwise it will not

Comment: Mohamed ,,, yes .. It was my mistake ..  thank you